# Call Web Api with Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am looking, but can't seem to find an answer. Basically I have a web API which would do the authentication and generate a token in which a new client application would send the credential and receive a token which then I would like to use identity for the `UserManager` implementation. However when creating a new asp.net core with identity (individual account) I must create a `DbContext` and a database directly with this.

I am curious is there a tutorial or is it even possible to call identity without having the clients to have its own database and just call a web API which receives a `JWT` response.

Maybe I am misunderstanding identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database will be required to store information about your users and their claims. You will need to register an authentication middleware for maintaining your identity tokens and claims on the user's web browser. A common middleware for consuming JWT is OpenID Connect. The following is an example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    // Allow sign in via an OpenId Connect provider
    services.AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options => {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/";
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["oidc:clientid"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["oidc:clientsecret"];
        options.Authority = Configuration["oidc:authority"];

        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    });
}
```

Additionally, another option is IdentityServer4 which supports OpenID Connect, OAuth2, and SAML2 with Sustainsys.Saml2. IdentityServer4 can act as a full identity provider that generates JWT, OAuth2 reference tokens, or SAML2 responses.

Answer (score 0):

Asp Net Identity supports jwt-token based authorization and authentification but it doesn't support generating jwt tokens. You can use third party services such as Auth0 to implement user batabase and token generation in your web api. If you want to implement it by yourself (which is a good idea for teaching, but bad for real world) there is a good [article](https://medium.com/@ozgurgul/asp-net-core-2-0-webapi-jwt-authentication-with-identity-mysql-3698eeba6ff8) for asp net core 2.0, but it's applicable to 3.1 with minor changes.

Comment: The web api solution has a generatejsontoken for jwt token, The issues I have is how to manage the token on the client application. I keep reading to install identity it needs its own dataase in the solution, witch is not what I want, I want the api to tell me if this user is authenticated or not

Comment: One the client side you can simply store jwt token as a cookie, which will be sent with every request. If user pressed "logout", simply delete the cookie

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with this? Why would you need your api to tell if the user is authenticated or not? If user provides a valid jwt token it means that he's authenticated . As far as I know jwt tokens shouldn't be stored in DB or smth. They are signed via secret key with guarantees that a token that was provided is not a fake one

Comment: The way i understand The client has a web form, witch then send the credentials (username and password) when login method is activated, this would return a token in witch I would need to store for future api calls or until the token his expire. But the database comes from the api not the client application

Comment: "But the database comes from the api not the client application" - what you are trying to say?

Comment: AspNetUsers table AspNetClaims and all those identity table they have to be stored there local msdb witch i dont want them to be. There the table from identity

Comment: Well those tables are part of a Asp Net Identity. They are needed for checking if user is really registered in application to give user a jwt token. If you don't want to store that in your local msdb, use 3rd party auth providers